# How to create a class and Frequency table in R

Tags: r, csv, frequency

I plotted a graph in R:

```
OBD=read.csv("OBD.CSV",header = TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
x1 <- OBD$Time1
x2 <- OBD$Time2
y1<-OBD$Vehicle_speed
y2 <-OBD$Engine_speed
par(mar=c(5,4,4,5)+.1)
plot(x1,y1,type="l",col="yellow",ylab = "Vehicle speed")
par(new=TRUE)
plot(x2,y2,type="l",col="blue4",xaxt="n",yaxt="n",xlab="Time",ylab="")
axis(4)
mtext("Engine speed",side=4,line=3)
legend("topleft",col=c("blue4","yellow"),lty=1,legend=c("y1","y2"))
```

My CSV file contains 82698 rows and 10 columns:

```
Engine_speed    Time2
650        0
650        0
650     0.001
651     0.001
600.5   0.202
600.5   0.202
600.5   0.202
600     0.203
600     0.203
600.5   0.203
1795    0.888
1800    0.888
1796    0.888
1800    0.888
1808.5  0.889
2038.5  1.217
2032    1.218
2036.5  1.218
2037.5  1.218
2028    1.218
2032.5  1.218
599.5   0.728
599.5   0.728
600     0.728
600     0.728
600     0.728
599.5   0.728
599.5   0.729
599.5   0.729
599.5   0.729
599.5   0.729
```

I want to get a min_engine speed, Max engine speed , standard deviation and Frequency.

```
Engine Speed    Frequency
Below 600   6818
600-800    12014
800-1000    2952
1000-1200   4443
1200-1400   7824
1400-1600   9969
1600-1800   12682
1800-2000   6794
2000-2200   9922
2200-2400   3790
2400-2600   5197
2600-2800   293
```

I got the class and frequency(I want to get the mode, I think R doesn't have a built in Mode) in excel. i want to make similar table in R too. I tried using dataframes.

```
Mode <- function(MD) 
  {
MDX <- unique(MD)
MDX[which.max(tabulate(match(MD, MDX)))]
}

table(OBD$Engine_speed)
```

I'm new to R. Please help me on this

Comment: `library(dplyr) ; df %>% count(Engine_speed = cut(Engine_speed, seq(400, 2800, by = 200), labels = paste(seq(400, 2600, by = 200), seq(600, 2800, by = 200), sep = '-')))`

Comment: or base: `data.frame(table(Engine_speed = cut(df$Engine_speed, breaks = seq(400, 2800, 200), labels = paste(seq(400, 2600, by = 200), seq(600, 2800, by = 200), sep = '-'))))` In both cases, most of it is just to make pretty labels; chop out that argument if you like.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, .N,
     .(Engine_speed = cut(Engine_speed, breaks = seq(400, 2800, by = 200)))]
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
aggregate(Time2~Engine_Speed, transform(df1, Engine_Speed = cut(Engine_speed,
           breaks = seq(400, 2800, by = 200))), FUN = length)
```